# Sufficient Conditions $DA^T+AD+I<0$ to Hold Based on Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-matrix-inequality

I want to find sufficient conditions for the following matrix inequality to hold:
$$DA^T+AD+I<0$$
based on the eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$, where $D$ is diagonal with negative entries and $A$ is diagonalizable with positive real eigenvalues.

I tried to write $A = T \Lambda T^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal so the inequality becomes
$$DT^{-T}\Lambda T^T + T \Lambda T^{-1}D + I < 0$$
$$T^{-1}DT^{-T}\Lambda + \Lambda T^{-1}DT^{-T} + T^{-1}T^{-T} < 0$$
$$S \Lambda + \Lambda S + Q < 0$$
where $S:=T^{-1}DT^{-T}$ and $Q := T^{-1}T^{-T}$, which is essentially the same problem with only difference $S$ being symmetric.

We can also write
$$ \lambda_\max(S\Lambda+\Lambda S) < -\lambda_\max(Q)$$
using symmetricity of the matrices. But I want to write something like
$$ 2 \lambda_\max(S) \lambda_\max(\Lambda) < -\lambda_\max(Q)$$
Is there any way to do this?

**Edit.** The solution (I think).
Let $x$ be such that
$$ x^T (DA^T+AD) x = \lambda_\max(DA^T+AD) $$
Now we can write $x = \sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ where $A^T v_i = \mu_i v_i$ with $\mu_i > 0$. So,
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_\max(DA^T+AD) &= x^T (DA^T+AD) x \\
&= x^T D A^T \sum_i \alpha_i v_i + \sum_i \alpha_i v_i^T A D x \\
&= x^T D \sum_i \alpha_i \mu_i v_i + \sum_i \alpha_i \mu_i v_i^T Dx \\
&\leq 2 \mu_\max x^T D x \\
&\leq 2 \mu_\max d_\max
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $2 \mu_\max d_\max < -1$ is a sufficient condition for the matrix inequality to hold.
Is everything all right with this proof?

Comment: @user1551 So ordering of eigenvalues changes the result. But can we say if $2 \lambda_i \mu_j+1<0, \forall i,j$ then the inequality holds as a conservative condition, where $\lambda_i, \mu_i$ are eigenvalues of $D$ and $A$ respectively.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking about necessary and sufficient conditions. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @user1551 No problem. Actually the comment was valuable to me. I didn't think of the simple diagonal case with different orderings of diagonal elements.

Comment: what does $\lambda_\max(\Lambda)$ mean?  presumably $\Lambda$ has complex diagonal elements / eigenvalues since all we know is *$A$ is diagonalizable*.

Comment: @user8675309 Yes you are right. We can assume that $A$ has real eigenvalues. I will edit my question.

Comment: working with the symmetric form: it should be immediate that its necessary for $\Lambda \succ \mathbf 0$ -- since you're trying to prove  $Q <  \Lambda (-S) +(-S) \Lambda = \Lambda B + B\Lambda$  so check the diagonals of the RHS given that $B, Q \succ\mathbf 0$

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you for pointing this out. We may also assume that $A$ has positive real eigenvalues.

Comment: the problem with your 'solution' is that you have written $x^T (AD) x  \leq \mu_\max d_\max$ which is not true when dealing with matrices that are not normal (and of course requires a constraint that $\big\Vert x \big \Vert_2=1$ which I assume was tacitly there).  It is true that $x^T (AD) x  \leq \big \Vert AD \big \Vert_2 \leq  \big \Vert A \big \Vert_2 \cdot d_\max$ but the maximal singular value of $A$ has very little to do with the maximal eigenvalue of $A$.  If you write $A$ in upper triangular form as I did in my Answer below, this becomes very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all matrices below have real scalars. Rearranging terms and using $\Sigma = -D$.

You're trying to find sufficient conditions, purely in terms of eigenvalues of $A$ and $\sigma_i$ to prove
$I\prec \Sigma A^T + A\Sigma $

I'll show it's impossible to use these  conditions to prove
$0 \prec \Sigma A^T + A\Sigma $
hence one cannot use them to find $I\prec \Sigma A^T + A\Sigma $

Suppose for a contradiction that we may characterize the positive definiteness of
$\big(\Sigma A^T + A\Sigma\big) $ by the eigenvalues of $A$ and the $\sigma_i$'s. and you have selected the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\Sigma$ in such a manner.     Note that $\big(\Sigma A^T + A\Sigma\big) $ is positive definite *iff* $A\Sigma $ is.  (If the below non-symmetrized argument makes you uncomfortable you can double everything and recover the symmetric version.)

Now consider the 2x2 case (with obvious blocked structure generalization to higher dim) and since this theorem holds for all choices of $A$, I select $A$ to be  upper triangular and

$A = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & z\\ 0 &\lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$
then
$\mathbf 1^T A\Sigma \mathbf 1 = \sigma_1\lambda_1 + \sigma_2 z + \sigma_2\lambda_2 \leq 0$

for
$ z \leq -\frac{-1}{\sigma_2}\big(\sigma_1\lambda_1 +  \sigma_2\lambda_2\big)$

which contractdicts the positive definiteness of $ A\Sigma$.

*book-keeping note:*
In the trivial case where $A\propto I$, then the above doesn't hold as $z$ is forced to be equal to zero.  But for all other cases the desired sufficient conditions in terms of eigenvalues of $A$ and $\Sigma$ don't exist.